# Generate certain depth Clifford random circuit by qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

To obtain knowledge about the pattern of errors occur in quantum circuits, random Clifford circuits are a good paradigm to use in that these kind of circuits can be efficiently simulated by a classical computer. In this case, we can get both ideal and noisy data (measured form a real quantum device) at the same time. Then, we can take the two set of data for further use, like what have been done by [Patrick Coles](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.01210) etc. In qiskit, random Clifford circuits are generated by the [`random_clifford` method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.random_clifford.html). One drawback of the method is that the circuit depth cannot be specified, which limit the usage of the method if one just want like a shallow-depth circuit, like in the case of [measurement error mitigation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14044) proposed the IBM team, where they used depth-4 random Clifford circuits. In a nutshell, how can one generate certain depth random Clifford circuits using qiskit?